# How to export a file in Db2 without character delimiter nor column delimiter?

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I would like to export a table in a similar way that a normal select is executed. I mean:

```
db2 -x "select varchar(SCHEMANAME, 16) SCHEMANAME,
varchar(OWNER, 10) OWNER,
varchar(OWNERTYPE, 10) OWNERTYPE
from syscat.schemata where SCHEMANAME like 'SYS%'"
```

And the output is:

```
SYSCAT           SYSIBM     S
SYSFUN           SYSIBM     S
SYSIBM           SYSIBM     S
SYSIBMADM        SYSIBM     S
SYSIBMINTERNAL   SYSIBM     S
SYSIBMTS         SYSIBM     S
SYSPROC          SYSIBM     S
SYSPUBLIC        SYSIBM     S
SYSSTAT          SYSIBM     S
SYSTOOLS         SYSIBM     S
```

I would like to generate the same via an export (fixed-length columns). I have tried:

```
db2 "export to myfile.csv of del
modified by coldelX20
SELECT *
from syscat.schemata"

db2 "export to myfile.csv of del
modified by nochardel coldelX20
SELECT *
from syscat.schemata"

db2 "export to myfile.csv of del
modified by chardelX21 coldelX20
SELECT *
from syscat.schemata"
```

And I got:

```
SQL3017N  A delimiter is not valid or is used more than once.
```

(Redirecting the output of a normal select is not an option).

Comment: Instead of export command, why not use `db2 -x "select... "` ?    You should explain why redirecting output of normal select is not an option, what is your rationale?

Comment: The execution of the queries is automatic with the same command option for all executions. Everything should be done with the script itself, no post processing, no changes fot the automatic mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

[Delimiter considerations for moving data](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dm.doc/doc/r0011047.html):

> **Delimiter restrictions**
>
> There are a number of restrictions in place that help prevent the
>   chosen delimiter character from being treated as a part of the data
>   being moved. First, delimiters are mutually exclusive. Second, **a
>   delimiter cannot be binary zero, a line-feed character, a
>   carriage-return, or a blank space**. As well, the default decimal point
>   (.) cannot be a string delimiter. Finally, in a DBCS environment, the
>   pipe (|) character delimiter is not supported.

Db2 `export` command doesn't support a space as a delimiter. Moreover, it doesn't right pad a value with spaces to the maximum column length in characters.
You may construct one column expression yourself like below:

```
select 
          char(schemaname, 20) 
-- ...
|| ' ' || char(create_time) 
--- ...
|| ' ' || char(coalesce(char(auditpolicyid), '-'), 11) 
-- ...
from syscat.schemata;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export to myfile.csv of del
modified by nochardel
select rpad(left(SCHEMANAME,16) , 16 ) ||
rpad(left(OWNER,10), 10 ) ||
rpad(left(OWNERTYPE,10), 10)
from  syscat.schemata
```